# / and index.php. How to eliminate this duplicate page issue?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

In my website root, I have an index.php and of course the rest of the pages. The problem is when I crawl my site either with a crawler or a sitemap crawler, etc, it reports 2 duplicated links

www.domain.com/
www.domain.com/index.php

How do I force tell my crawler that there are no two instances of the same page? Do I use a 301 to merge them? A canonical? an .htaccess redirection? etc. How do I fix this?

Comment: Here is the htaccess code, if you needed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains

Comment: If you choose the shorter one, make sure the other pages on your website point to "/" and not to "index.php".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical URL or 301 redirect would both work fine. I'd go with the 301 redirect as it means only one URL pulls up that content which is good for both users and search engines. But the canonical URL is easier to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that was the answer. I kind of needed confirmation. But it still intrigues me that the search engines and crawlers are seeing two pages when they are the same. Weird.